# notepad++ ctrl-shift-t opens file instead of coping line to clipboard. Why?

Tags: notepad++

Here it says http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Keyboard_And_Mouse_Shortcuts Ctrl-Shift-T  Copy current line to clipboard  and it did it, before i upgrade to 7.3.2, now it just opens some text file (maybe previously opened i don't recognize the pattern) any suggestions on how to make it do what it should do? Thanks!

Comment: you may have keyboard shortcut overridden by any other plugin/command. You can go to `Settings > Shortcut Mapper` and check if you have the same keyboard shortcut for other command. If you find an item with same shortcut, double click on it to change them. See if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that some other command "hijacked" the shortcut. You need to look into `Settings` -> `Shortcut Mapper...` Menu:

- click on each button `Main menu`, `Macros` and so on
- look into each list until you find the assignments for `Ctrl-Shift-T`.
- delete the wrong keybinding using the `Modify` button
- if you are lucky thats it. (You have deleted the second binding that you want to get rid of (and the other binding, that you want to keep, is still there).)
- if the wanted keybinding is not there anymore you have to find the right command and assign the shortcut to it again

**Hint**

In my config on notepad++ Ctrl-Shift-T is assigned to

- `Restore Recent Closed File` on `Main menu` button (I think you want to delete this, or assign it another shortcut)
- `SCI_LINECOPY` on near the end on `Scintilla command` button (I think you want to keep/restore this)

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Notepad++ (e.g. v7.5.1), the following shortcut can be used to copy the current line: `Ctrl+Shift+X`

In the Shortcut mapper of Notepad++ this is found under Scintilla commands:
Name: `SCI_LINECOPY`
Shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+X`